# values ​in jpgraph v4.3.1 bar graph

Tags: codeigniter, jpgraph

Hello Lovers of programming, I have the following problem with the jpgraph v4.3.1 library, I want to put the values ​​above each bar but it does not show me anything, this is my code

```
    $data1y=$cantMasc;
    $data2y=$cantFem;
    $maximo = max(max($data1y,$data2y))+10;
    $graph = new Graph(650, 305, "auto");
    $graph->SetScale("textlin"); 
    $graph->xaxis->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_NORMAL,9);
    $graph->yaxis->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_NORMAL,9);
    $graph->xgrid->Show();
    $graph->ygrid->SetFill(false);
    $graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels($tipoResultado);
    $graph->xaxis->SetFont(FF_ARIAL, FS_BOLD, 10);
    $graph->yaxis->HideLine(false);
    $graph->yaxis->HideTicks(false,false);
    $graph->yaxis->scale->SetAutoMax($maximo);
    $graph->SetBox(false);
    $b1plot = new BarPlot($data1y);
    $b1plot->SetLegend("Masculino");
    $b1plot->value->Show();
    $b1plot->SetCenter(0.4);
    $b2plot = new BarPlot($data2y);
    $b2plot->SetLegend("Femenino");
    $b2plot->value->Show();
    $gbplot = new GroupBarPlot(array($b1plot,$b2plot));
    @unlink(APPPATH."../assets/images/$nomGraf.png");        
    $graph->Add($gbplot);
    $graph->legend->Pos(0.5, 0.99, 'center', 'bottom');
    $graph->legend->SetFont(FF_ARIAL, FS_BOLD, 11);        
    $graph->Stroke(APPPATH."../assets/images/$nomGraf.png");
    $this->Image(APPPATH."../assets/images/$nomGraf.png", 120, 35, 120, 70);
    $this->SetAlpha(1);
```

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Este es un sitio de habla inglesa. Intenta preguntar en https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: ok it's already translated